# Internet Explorer XSS filter goes off when submitting a form?

Tags: php, html, validation, xss, w3c

I have a page that is to be validated by w3c. In the developer menu, I have a validation link that looks something like this:

```
<form action="http://validator.w3.org/check" method="post" style="display:inline">
<textarea name="fragment" cols='0' rows='0' style="display:none;">{$page_content}</textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()" title="Validate the XHTML of this page.">XHTML</a>
</form>
```

$page_content is a string that contains the source code of the page. When I stored the source code, I use htmlspecialchars to encode the special characters. This validation link works fine on Chrome and FireFox, but on the Internet Explore, when I hit the submit link, the browser stops with an error message saying that it has modified the page to help prevent cross-site scripting.

Is there another way to go around this problem? You can give w3c the URI of the page to be validated, but a user has to be logged in with an id in order to see the page I'm trying to validate. I appreciate all inputs in advance. Thank you :)

Edit: My ultimate goal is to have a link that will submit my page's source code to w3c's XHTML validator.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `Cross-site Scripting (XSS) Filter` enabled in the browser.

This can be solved by disbaling xss filter.

Check [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/eb30323a-94f9-4417-905c-6a44ca8b0efc/internet-explorer-has-modified-this-page-to-prevent-cross-site-scripting-why-is-this-coming-up?forum=itprovistaapps) on how to disable it

Answer (score 0):

The only way around it without modifying browser settings is to set up a proxy script on your server that will forward data to `http://validator.w3.org/check` using libcurl and print the result. This way all cross-site traffic is moved to the server side where there are no such restrictions.

There are other options, such as setting up your own local copy of the validator. [See the validator documentation](http://validator.w3.org/docs/users.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable IE's XSS filter on a per-page basis by sending the [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd565647(v=vs.85).aspx#remediation) HTTP header.

```
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```